# Match LocalDateTime using Hamcrest in MVC Test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I'm struggeling implementing a Spring MVC Controller Test for a `LocalDateTime` field using Mockito and Hamcrest.

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = FooController.class)
class FooControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private FooService fooService;

  @Test
  void testController() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo(LocalDateTime.now());
    List<Foo> allFoos = Arrays.asList(foo);

    given(fooService.getAllFoos()).willReturn(allFoos);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/foos").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].timeOfUpdate", equalTo(foo.getTimeOfUpdate()), LocalDateTime.class));
  }
}
```

The Controller returns a JSON serialized Object `Foo` which looks like that:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Foo {
  private LocalDateTime timeOfUpdate;
}
```

The JSON Response looks like this:

```
[
  {
     "timeOfUpdate":"2020-08-05T18:40:30.7416748"
  }
]
```

However when I'm trying to Match the field `timeOfUpdate` with `equalTo` I recieve the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$[0].timeOfUpdate"
Expected: <2020-08-05T18:40:30.741674800>
     but: was "2020-08-05T18:40:30.7416748"
```

So It seems to be a precision error, but I have no clue how to resolve this.

**Update:**

I've changed the Matcher to the following:

```java
andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].timeOfUpdate").value(foo.getTimeOfUpdate()));
```

Now it seems to coerce the types right but the assertion still fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$[0].timeOfUpdate" expected:<2020-08-05T19:19:05.739893500> but was:<2020-08-05T19:19:05.7398935>
Expected :2020-08-05T19:19:05.739893500
Actual   :2020-08-05T19:19:05.7398935
```

**Update 2**

Here's one workaround to get the tests green:

```java
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].statusRecord.timeOfUpdate", is(person.getStatusRecord().getTimeOfUpdate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")))));
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Foo {
  @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
  private LocalDateTime timeOfUpdate;
}
```

Comment: The message seems to indicate a type error, not a precision error. I say that based on the angle brackets and double quotes. Are you sure `jsonPath()` is converting to `LocalDateTime` before comparing? Also, I don't think it's a problem here yet, but you should inject a `Clock` instance into your service if you want to test the times it's generating. Otherwise you will eventually run into spurious errors due to actual precision, not formatting.

Comment: @erickson Thanks! You're absolutly right. I've edited the question and found a way to coerce the types right. However the AssertionError still occures and now it seems to be clear that it's due to the precision.

Comment: Your workaround seems good if you're set on using `LocalDateTime`. In general, this format can't preserve the absolute time even if the recipient can infer the time zone, because of autumn daylight saving transitions. I'd recommend using an `Instant` for API signatures, and serializing as an `ISO_INSTANT` or `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` so that clients don't have to guess what time you really meant. It might also be helpful to limit the precision as you've done here to seconds or milliseconds for widest interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `toString()` for `.value(foo.getTimeOfUpdate().toString())`
as `jsonPath("$[0].timeOfUpdate"` is json string.
I have also faced the same issue.

Here is your test class looks like after the change.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = FooController.class)
class FooControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private FooService fooService;

  @Test
  void testController() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo(LocalDateTime.now());
    List<Foo> allFoos = Arrays.asList(foo);

    given(fooService.getAllFoos()).willReturn(allFoos);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/foos").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].timeOfUpdate").value(foo.getTimeOfUpdate().toString()));
  }
}
```